# postMessage in beforeunload fails

Tags: javascript, events, iframe, ionic2, message

I'm seeing that when `postMessage()` is called within a `beforeunload` window event in an Ionic 2 browser, the message never reaches the parent. If the same message is posted in the `unload` or `load` event, it is successfully received. In JQuery:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    parent.postMessage('TheMessage', 'domain.com');  //NOT received by parent
});     

$(window).on('unload', function() {
    parent.postMessage('TheMessage', 'domain.com');  //Received by parent
});

$(window).load(function(){
    parent.postMessage('TheMessage', 'domain.com');  //Received by parent
});
```

In this case we are posting from an IFrame to the parent and both webpages are controlled by the same owner but come from different domains.

Is this the expected behaviour? I see that [`alert` is not allowed in `beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) but don't see any rules about `postMessage`:

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be
>   ignored during this event.

Is there any way to use `postMessage` in `beforeunload`?

Answer (score 1):

This only happens in iOS and there appears to be no way to change it. In Android, beforeunload is fired as expected.